# Pull mysql database into elasticsearch

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch, jdbc, webdriver

I am using elasticsearch in my project and my requirement pulling a large MySQL data into Elasticsearch using Elasticsearch JDBC River plugin. My need is to sync mysql table to elasticsearch so i'm creating a mapping for jdbc river index.

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/city -d '
{
  "mappings" : {
    "city_type": {
      "properties" : {
        "domain" : {
          "type" : "multi_field",
          "fields" : {
            "domain" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "index" : "analyzed"
            },
            "exact" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "index" : "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "sent_date" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

After creating the mapping in elasticsearch . i want to load the mysql table data into it. so i'm using the following command.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/river/city/_meta?pretty' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "root",
        "sql" : "select id as _id,id as domain from city;",
    "strategy":"oneshot"
    },
    "index" :{
        "index" : "city",
        "type" : "city_type",
    "bulk_size":500
    }
}'
```

These queries are successfully run and after these query when i run the command to find the data in elasticsearch is empty.

```
http://localhost:9200/river/_search?pretty&q=*
```

Please check the response of the above query [here](https://gist.github.com/imsonujangra/f23c6054512fb0132ee81b146121fd06). Why the data is not showing in the elasticsearch query please help.

Answer (score 0):

River has been deprecated https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10345 by the way.

I would highly recommend jprante jdbc importer which is a java stand-alone allowing to do the operations you are needing. https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc. It is not exactly a river as you have defined one.

Concerning your question, could you please try http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty&q=* ? With your syntax, you are actually looking for data in index river. You should look on all index with the query I wrote or in city index : http://localhost:9200/city/city_type/_search?pretty&q=*

Comment: when i try to use jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc in my project . In /usr/share/elasticsearch directory wget http://xbib.org/repository/org/xbib/elasticsearch/importer/elasticsearch-jdbc/2.1.0/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.1.0-dist.zip . Then extract the zip and move the elasticsearch jdbc and mysqlconnector java to my lib folder. But elasticsearch is failed to start.

Comment: This is not a lib! You should use it outside of your elasticsearch folder. That might be the issue. By the way, the plugin is packed with the sql connector so you don't need to put your mysqlconnector to your lib folder. To sum up, move jdbc outside of the lib folder + remove your mysqlconnector

Comment: Can you please show the log of elasticsearch if the precedent comment is not helping ?

Comment: now working after installing https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc. is it good idea to sync the mysql database with elasticsearch because i'm worried about performance of mysql because so much loads on mysql as well as elastic and other option for sync is to plan a cron and pic last updated record from mysql.Currently i'm using cron to sync with mysql bt always there is a mismatch between mysql and elasticsearch.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. I don't pull all data every time! Every time a data is updated (or created) I refresh a field in db to keep track of last modification. And I use a criterion on that date update to query only needed date from the plugin. The link below might help you, I would go on that kind of solution instead of a timestamp based solution if I had to rewrite the pipeline. By the way, jprante's plugin can handle synchro (see schedule field) and you can see a $metrics.lastexecutionstart!
https://qafoo.com/blog/086_how_to_synchronize_a_database_with_elastic_search.html

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your shoes, I would use logstash to push the data from MySQL to Elastic. River is deprecated since a long time ago as @Artholl already mentioned.

See https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin